Make URL configurable by reading from appsettings.json file in a blazor page
I have a blazor project and I wanted to make my page URL configurable by reading from appsettings.json file. I have tried the following
Login.razor page
@page "LOGIN_URL"

appsettings.json file
"LOGIN_URL": "496436/login"

This is what I wanted. But I am not able to find a solution for the same and according to the values in appsettings.json, the url should automatically change or reflect in Login page.

You couldn't do this, one possible way is using the NavigationManager to create a custom redirect based on the json file .

There isn't a way to do it with the @page directive. This isn't possible because @page "/" turns behind the scene into the [Route("/")] attribute and parameters of an attribut have to be constants.
A very cumbersome way to achieve this but also the single one i could imagine is to implement something like custom routing. You could check inside of Routes.razor whether the request path matches the configured path and render the login page if so but as I already said this a very cumbersome. Genraley isn't it planned at all to do routing dynamicly like this.
